# Choose Randomly from Names of Certain Sub-Directories (Filtered by Naming Pattern)

Tags: php, html, arrays, random

Okay, I've re-written this question a few times now as I figure things out. So, I have a directory `images`. It contains 66 sub-directories which follow a `date_filenumber` (`YYYYMMDD_1234`) format and contain an image, and a handful of other subdirectories which do not. I want to get just the 66, select one of them at random, and then insert the path to its image into HTML. I'm almost there:

```
PHP
$A = glob('images/????????_????');
$B = array_rand($A);
$path = ($A[$B]).'/1x.jpg'

HTML
<img src="<?php echo $path;?>">
```

But that gives me `<img src="images/YYYYMMDD_1234/1x.jpg"`. I want just `<img src="YYYYMMDD_1234/1x.jpg">`.

That's where I'm stuck. ideas?

Answer (score 2):

`glob()` for directories using `GLOB_ONLYDIR` (in case there might be files there) and then exclude *includes* with `preg_grep()` using `PREG_GREP_INVERT`:

```
$dirs = preg_grep('/includes/', glob('images/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR), PREG_GREP_INVERT);
```

If in the future you add other directories that you don't want, then get only the ones that match your naming pattern:

```
$dirs = preg_grep('/\d{8}_\d{4}$/', glob('images/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR));
```

Or for your simple pattern:

```
$dirs = glob('*_*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
```

Comment: Thanks for turning me on to `glob`. BTW it turns out `preg_grep` isn't even necessary; you can get the same array using a naming pattern within `glob` itself: `glob('images/*_*')` in this case. However it turns out that didn't get me the data format I needed and so I've completely re-written the question if you have any more suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Use `glob()` and `substr()`:

```
$foldersArray = array();
foreach(glob('images/*') as $folder)  {

    if (strpos($folder, "includes") !== 0) {
        if (strpos($folder, ".") === false) $foldersArray[] = $folder; //exclude files
    }

}
```